# Statistics on temp tables

Tags: sql-server, statistics, temporary-tables

Quick and simple... why is this sp failing when I attempt to retrieve statistics for one of the columns on the temp table?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Demo
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Declare table variable
CREATE TABLE #temp_table (ID INT)
DECLARE @I INT = 0

-- Insert 10K rows
    WHILE @I < 100
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #temp_table VALUES (@I)

        SET @I=@I+1
    END

-- Display all rows and output execution plan (now the EstimateRow is just fine!)
SELECT * FROM #temp_table

-- Is the object there
SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table')

-- How about statistics
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('tempdb..#temp_table', 'id')
END;
```

I don't understand, I get a message saying that there is no statistics created on column id

```
Could not locate statistics 'id' in the system catalogs.
```

Having said that, I have seen an article by Paul White where this technique is used and does indeed work.

https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2012/08/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to explicitly create a statistics object called `id`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Demo
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Declare table variable
CREATE TABLE #temp_table (ID INT)
DECLARE @I INT = 0

CREATE STATISTICS id ON #temp_table (ID)

-- Insert 10K rows
    WHILE @I < 100
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #temp_table VALUES (@I)

        SET @I=@I+1
    END

-- Display all rows and output execution plan (now the EstimateRow is just fine!)
SELECT * FROM #temp_table

-- Is the object there
SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table')

-- How about statistics
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('tempdb..#temp_table', 'id')
END;

EXEC dbo.Demo
```

When left to its own devices, the statistics objects created by the system have odd names like `_WA_Sys_00000002_5F141958`

Just note that when you create the statistics matters -- you'll need to move the `CREATE STATISTICS` command to after you populate the temp table with data if you want it to show anything, or possibly change your query to *need* to update stats, like `SELECT * FROM #temp_table WHERE ID > 0`.

Comment: I realized that the key thing here (in your answer) as far as I'm concerned, is the "change your query to need to update stats" because, even without issuing a CREATE STATISTICS, my sample sp will not fail as long as the query involves using that column (which is precisely what Paul White did in his article).

Comment: I changed my original SP to include a WHERE clause in the SELECT * FROM #temp_table and things were good (like I said, even without the CREATE STATISTICS statement).